Convert Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Path to MAUI
I want to draw a circle within a grid. My old Xamarin code looked like this:
public int DrawCircle(Brush colour, int strokeThickness, int x, int y, int width, int height, Grid cv)
{
    Path c1 = new Path();
    c1.Stroke = colour;
    c1.Fill = transparentBrush;
    c1.StrokeThickness = strokeThickness;
    EllipseGeometry myEllipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry();
    myEllipseGeometry.Center = new Point(x, y);
    myEllipseGeometry.RadiusX = height;
    myEllipseGeometry.RadiusY = width;
    c1.Data = myEllipseGeometry;
    cv.Children.Add(c1);

    return cv.Children.Count - 1;
}

I can't seem to figure out the MAUI way of doing this.
Thanks in advance


Convert Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Path to MAUI

The Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Path in xamarin is same as the Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shapes.Path in maui.
So you can add the following name space and then use your code directly.
using Path = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shapes.Path;


I don't see what is exactly the issue of your code after migrating.
If you only care about the circle being centered inside the grid then you can use directly Ellipse instead of EllipseGeometry.
The below example ensures to draw a centered circle inside the Grid; with a diameter equals to the minimum between your Grid's Width and Height.
private int Draw(Brush colour, int strokeThickness, Grid cv)
    {
        Ellipse myEllipse = new()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HeightRequest = cv.Height > cv.Width ? cv.Width : cv.Height,
            WidthRequest = cv.Height > cv.Width ? cv.Width : cv.Height,
            Stroke = Colors.Red,
            StrokeThickness = strokeThickness,
        };

        cv.Children.Add(myEllipse);

        return cv.Children.Count - 1;
    }

If you don't care to draw an ellipse instead of a circle (if the grid width and height are not equal) then replace with:
HeightRequest = cv.Height,
WidthRequest = cv.Width,

